# show data in text from api in swiftui

Tags: api, swiftui

I've been staring at this simple task for a while now and am not seeing what i'm doing wrong and why I'm getting and error

My API response is:
{"risks":"4","actions":"12","issues":"1","decisions":"3"}

my swiftui code is:

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbGTB.png)

The obvious question is:  what am I doing wrong to get the content of "risks" (which is 4) from the API displayed in the "Text" in line 43. I just don't see it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post code (text), not images.

Comment: show your code as text, not as a picture. `raids` is an array, and so has no `risks` as the error tells you. You need to decide which element of the array you want to use, for example `raids[0].risks`.

Comment: I tried posting (my first posting here) as code,  but it messed up the message completely.  Sorry for that one :)

Comment: Thank you workingDog.  That answer actually made all the sense!.  I just got stuck.

Comment: yes, I understand, the UI is not great, I always feel like I'm in a tank, looking through the rectangle hole. Select you code, then use the `{}` thing to make it look good.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it eventually the following way:

(Props to @workingdog.  Thx bro for putting me in the right thinking path)

```
struct Post: Decodable {
    var risks: String
    var actions: String
    var issues: String
    var decisions: String
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var lijst = Post(risks: "0", actions: "0", issues: "0", decisions: "0")
    
    func getPosts() {
        let urlString = "https://pmo-online.com/someAPI~~~~~~~~~~"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, _, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Post.self, from: data)
                        self.lijst = decodedData
                    } catch {
                        print ("Error! Something went wrong")
                
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.black)
                        .frame(width:55)
                    Text("\(lijst.risks)")
                        .font(Font.system(.title2, design: .default))
                }


}
```